# Ошибка при установке модуля pygame на mac os

Tags: python, pygame, mac

[image: при попытке установки pygame с помощью pip install pygame выдает это:]

при попытке установки pygame с помощью pip install pygame выдает это:
пробовала переустановить pip. На ноуте стоит python версии 3.10
пыталась установить с помощью easy_install pygame и чере pycharm

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вот это читали? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59334195/sdl-h-error-when-installing-pygame-on-mac

Comment: И ещё вот это https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/139